# Convert string to date in pymongo

Tags: mongodb, python-3.6, pymongo

Using Community MongoDB 4.4.3, I have a sample test collection:

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.test
collection = db.test_collection
print(collection.find_one())

>>> {'_id': ObjectId('600d8e2f4cf39c04cdb86ea0'),
 'id': '0706.1314',
 'update_date': '2008-12-18'}
```

I'm trying to convert string to date for the field `update_date` with [$toDate operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/):

```
collection.aggregate([{"$toDate": "update_date"}])
```

But get the following error:

```
OperationFailure: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$toDate', full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$toDate'", 'code': 40324, 'codeName': 'Location40324'}
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: You should use [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the input field as follow:

```
 collection.aggregate([  {$project:{ newField:{"$toDate": "$update_date"}}}       ])
```

Comment: This `collection.aggregate([{"$toDate": "$update_date"}])` gives the same error `OperationFailure: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$toDate'`

Comment: you need to assigne the value to field and easiest is to do it in $project stage , chek the updated answer